# Dependency issue with Spark and Google cloud Firestore with SBT

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, sbt

My project runs without issues in Intellij sbt console.

But after compiling with sbt assembly when I run the jar with spark-submit, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
```

I tried a lot of different things around my dependencies, following GCP advice [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc)

I use sbt with assembly plugin.

Here's my sbt file :

```
name := "firestore-dump"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.firebase" % "firebase-admin" % "6.11.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.yaml" % "snakeyaml" % "1.18"
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.3.0"

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  entry: String => {
    val strategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(entry)
    if (strategy == MergeStrategy.deduplicate) MergeStrategy.first
    else strategy
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Guava's `Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, String, Object)` has been introduced since Guava 20.0. I guess your dependency has old version.

https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkArgument-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Would you try declaring Guava dependency > 20.0? Such as

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" %% "guava" % "26.0-android"
```